# Should we have a tag to identify questions concerning specific published papers?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just editing [Trying to understand free-energy equations in a Karl Friston neuroscience article](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/726/322) and thought it might be useful to have a tag identifying questions specifically concerning one or more published academic works.

Would this be useful, and if so, what would be a good name for the tag? It seems a bit similar to [the `[specific-question]` tag on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info), so [specific-article](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-article) comes to mind as a possibility; but maybe something more general like [published-science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-science) would be better.

Answer (score 4):

I hadn't noticed [specific-question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-question); my first reaction was that it doesn't add much value to say "this is a question about something in particular" since presumably most questions are. But I get it.

[published-paper](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-paper)? published-something seems reasonable to denote that it's a question about known research, maybe.

Comment: I agree that 'specific-question' doesn't add any value. Most questions should be reasonably specific. Tags, theoretically, should be used to classify our content. This one doesn't really add any value. However, I agree that having one for published-papers would be more valuable. Or, maybe research-topic.