# Are questions about papers on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've seen that there was a [discussion a few years ago](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98/should-we-have-a-tag-to-identify-questions-concerning-specific-published-papers/99#99) about papers on Data Science SE and I'd like to revive it.

I am a bit fuzzy about whether questions about papers are or should be considered on-topic. Maybe there is a distinction between:

- A specific question about a part of the paper (i.e., how should I interpret this equation?)
- A general question about the paper (i.e. what dataset did they use? Is there an implementation? How to contact the author?)
- A discussion question about the implication of the paper?

I would assume that the first one is fine and that the others probably aren't.

Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 5):

It seems about right.

- Case 1: would be a common question.
- Case 2: would probably be downvoted since it would be a question that doesn't show much effort, if a accepted paper doesn't give that kind of clarification it is probably is from a low quality publisher. Also, SE Academia should be used to ask more general questions about publishing/getting information about academic articles.
- Case 3: probably would lead to a opinion-based question, which should be closed.